# how to design jQuery based pagination

Tags: jquery, html, css, feed, html-lists

I would like to create a pagination function in jQuery, my code as follows:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="">1</li>
    <li class="inactive">2</li>
    <li><a id="qp3" class="apager" href="/3">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="qp4" class="apager" href="/4">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="qp5" class="apager" href="/5">5</a></li>
    <li><a id="nqp2" class="apager" href="/2">next</a></li>
</ul>
```

When someone clicks a link, I would like to show which link they have clicked on and remove the class `.inactive` - the Anchor tag should be removed also.

How can I copy the Anchor into every `<li>`?

*[edited by Neuroflux, apologies if I got the question wrong...]*

Comment: I have edited your question, hope I got the correct wording - it was hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the jQuery website, they have many articles [like this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination) and [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/paginate) to help you out with your problem. :)

They have demonstrations to show you how they work and guidelines for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination) , this plugin is good. This is looking similar to the control used in stackoverflow paging